# Handling of binary data with Python + psycopg2 (DB: Postgres 9.5)

Tags: python, psycopg2

Lets say I have table test with columns id (of *bigint* type) & data (of *bytea* type).

I don't want to display actual binary data from column **data** when I execute below query in Python.

```
select * from test;
```

I just want a place holder which display `<binary data>` or `<BLOB>`, because some of data are in hundreds of MB in that column which does not make any sense to display binary data in column.
[image]

---

Is it possible to identify and replace binary data with place holder in psycopg2 ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "testdb", user = "postgres", password = "pass123", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
print "Opened database successfully"

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT id, data from test")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print("ID = ", row[0])
   print("DATA = ", row[1])


print "Operation done successfully";
conn.close()
```

We fetch the result from database and generate html report from the result, here user can provide any query in html textbox so query is not static, we execute that query and generate the html table. This is in-house report generation script.

Comment: I don't get it. Display where? You didn't post a single line of Python code. Why do you query for `data` if you are not going to display it? Just ignore it in your sql query and put `<BLOB>` in the output.

Comment: @freakish added sample code

Comment: Again, just don't query for `data` and do `print("DATA = <BLOB>")`. Or if you wanna make sure that there's actually something in data then do for example `print("DATA = ", row[1][:10])`. But I don't see any point in loading megabytes from db if you are not going to use it.

Comment: If the query is static than I could have done that but In my case user can enter any query in textbox and we display the result in html table.

Comment: Oh, this is **extremely** unsafe (one minor problem you've already noticed - overloading the db), I wouldn't go down that road. Anyway one way would be to create a special view for that and revoke access to the `test` table.

Comment: This is in-house application for report generation and not exposed to outside world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is bytea you can write your own bytea typecaster as an object that wraps a binary string.

Note that the data is fetched and sent on the network anyway. If you don't want that overhead just don't select those fields.

```
>>> import psycopg2

>>> class Wrapper:
...     def __init__(self, thing):
...         self.thing = thing
...         

>>> psycopg2.extensions.register_type(
...     psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
...         psycopg2.BINARY.values, "WRAPPER", lambda x, cur: Wrapper(x)))

>>> cnn = psycopg2.connect('')
>>> cur = cnn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("create table btest(id serial primary key, data bytea)")
>>> cur.execute("insert into btest (data) values ('foobar')")
>>> cur.execute("select * from btest")
>>> r = cur.fetchone()
>>> r
(1, <__main__.Wrapper instance at 0x7fb8740eba70>)
>>> r[1].thing
'\\x666f6f626172'
```

Please refer to the documentation for the `extensions` functions used.